# load virtualenv/batch files in vim?

Tags: windows, vim

I have activate.bat with some other configuration that is crucial for my python apps. It seems like vim has a way to get into a virtualenv by using its built-in python features, but I don't see a way to call a batch file inside vim.

it is trivial to load a batch file from other batch file, like:

**foo.bat**

```
set "FOO=BAR"
```

**bar.bat**

```
call foo.bat
echo %FOO% #outputs bar
```

how do I load external batch file into vim that I can use variables declared from it? I'm on windows 7 and I use `gvim 7.4`.

Comment: does the batch file activate the virtualenv and you want vim to also activate the virtualenv when editing?

Comment: @aalizadeh yes, that batch file activates the virtualenv and I want to load it with vim, that external commands launched from vim are executed on the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at: https://github.com/jmcantrell/vim-virtualenv and http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3840. These are great for working with virtualenvs within python. They are kinda like `virtualenvwrapper` for Vim.